# Ansible, save variable content to new file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create an Ansible task to save the content of a variable to a new file.

Using Ansible 2.5.13 and Python 2.7.5.

I've tried already to copy the content of the variable to a destination path where the file should be created...

```
  - name: Save alert rule example file to Prometheus
    copy:
      content: "{{ alert_rule_config }}"
      dest: /opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml
```

Tried also to create the file before copying the content of the variable

```
  - name: Create alert rule file
    file:
      path: /opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml
      state: touch

  - name: Save alert rule example file to Prometheus
    copy:
      content: "{{ alert_rule_config }}"
      dest: /opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml
```

Tried to wrap the destination path in quotes...
But no matter what a directory `/opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml/` is created!

The content of the variable is something like

```
  alert_rule_config:
    groups:
      - name: debug-metrics
        rules:
          - alert: DebugAlert
            expr: test_expression
```

I expect the file to be created (because it does not exist) and the content of the variable to be saved to the newly created file but the task fails with

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "can not use content with a dir as dest"}`

I want to avoid issuing a command and would prefer to use an Ansible module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the target directory instead of the target file, or you will get `Destination directory /opt/compose/prom does not exist` in the first option or `Error, could not touch target: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml'` in the second option.

```
- name: Create alert rule containing directory
  file:
    path: /opt/compose/prom/
    state: directory
- name: Save alert rule example file to Prometheus
  copy:
    content: "{{ alert_rule_config }}"
    dest: /opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml
```

But as @Calum Halpin says, if during your tests you did an error and created a directory `/opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml/`, you need to remove it before.

Comment: alert_rule.yml was being created (as a post_task in the playbook) and in a role in docker-compose there was a volume being mapped with that filename. The problem seems to have been that the docker container was started before the file being copied, so, I believe the directory was created by docker-compose because of the volume... I ended up creating pre_tasks like you proposed, so, when the docker container starts the file is already there and the volume is mapped with no problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if a directory `/opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml` already exists when your tasks are run.

To remove it as part of your tasks add

```
- file:
    path: /opt/compose/prom/alert_rule.yml
    state: absent
```

ahead of your other tasks.

Comment: i believe your solution could also work. I suspect the directory was created by docker-compose inside a role. I ended up moving the task of adding the file as a pre_task